# SDL_Init_Everything fails in C

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am trying to create a game in C using SDL. After some time of debugging I found an error at SDL_Init:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Init attempt\n");
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed at SDL init: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    fflush(stderr);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Init success\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
Init attempt
```

Somehow the fprintf inside the write function is getting executed.

The gcc command I used is:
`gcc -Wextra -Wall -pedantic program.c -lpthread -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf`

Note: If I use g++, everything works fine. However, I must use gcc.

Is there a way to fix the error?

Comment: Flush stderr before the exit? And log the error from SDL_GetError

Comment: Perhaps reduce the code to a minimal example that compiles but fails when it runs. That is, no `...` and no `frpintf` typos.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. I will update the question once I finish

Comment: 'write' is an os function that you're redefining (it's undefined behavior)

Comment: Oh ok, that makes a lot of sense. It really confused me :D

The cause of the problem is the initialisation of the audio subsystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the official doc (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init) there's a flag that might conflict with your setup: `SDL_INIT_HAPTIC`

i didn't get any error or crash so im not sure, but it is possible that this flag might be included in the EVERYTHING one, and if so:

```
It’s disabled by default if you don’t use ./configure; make style builds.
Otherwise it’ll happily build if your headers are new enough.
```

(https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl2-sdl-init-sdl-init-everything-failing/19250)

did you try setting up by flags you only need, like `SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO` and see if this works?

Comment: are you linking everything you're initializing from the SDL? might be worth a try :)

Comment: I was wrong, if I do not initialise SDL_INIT_AUDIO I do not get the error anymore.

Comment: great to hear! ;)