# Can't initialize SDL2, but SDL_GetError() return nothing

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2

I am just trying to launch a simple SDL2 example. Compiling is ok, but in time of executing, in this code:

```
bool init(){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL init error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I get `SDL init error:`  without any output from SDL_GetError(). Can you tell me, what is the problem?

IDE: Eclipse, OS: Ubuntu.

Update:

The shown piece of code contained an minimal reproducible example. But if you insist, then this code gives the same error:

```
int main(){

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL init error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Update 2:

If I add some more code:

```
int main(){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL init error: " << SDL_GetError() << " |" << std::endl;
//      return false;
    }
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", 200, 200, 460, 200, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window == nullptr){
        std::cout << "SDL create window error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
//      return false;
    }
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if(renderer == nullptr){
        std::cout << "SDL create renderer error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
//      return false;
    }
```

If I add more code to the project, I get the same error. That is, during initialization on the first check. Further execution occurs without errors, a window and a renderer are created. But the renderer cannot draw anything, the window is always black and no drawing commands are executed:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xAA, 0xFF, 0xFF);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
SDL_Rect actor1 = {10, 10, 550, 50};
SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &actor1);
```

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  There's no telling what context `init()` is being called in, could be gnarly thread tomfoolery for all we know.

Comment: The shown piece of code contained an minimal reproducible example. But if you insist, then this code gives the same error:

Comment: Followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373990/sdl-init-everything-fails-in-c
I found that problem is in initialization of audio system. Any advices?